# no image received in rviz (turtlebot sim)

Tags: ros, gazebo, rviz, turtlebot, tutorial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I have just started with Ubuntu, ROS and Gazebo so I really do not know much yet. However, I really want to learn as much as possible and as fast as possible so please help me.

I am going through the tutorials for the turtlebot simulation on Gazebo after going through the tutorial from gazebosim. I can make the robot move with the command but I am having issues with the RViz parts. In the first tutorial, when I open RVIZ, to visualize my world in Gazebo, I have a warning for the image. It displays no image received. I can still see the obstacles added to the world with the point cloud. Do you know why I am not receiving any image?

USing Hydro and gazebo 1.9

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197359/no-image-received-in-rviz-(turtlebot-sim)/) by [turtlebot_lille](https://answers.ros.org/users/20798/turtlebot_lille/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-11-13

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It might be that the rviz config is connected to the wrong topic. See if there's another topic available to select for the image.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-10-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

tfoote, thanks for your answer. I had the same problem and used your advice.

1. Firstly, I'd like to add more
   detailed answer.

   Edit the parameter **"Image"->"Image
   Topic"**  to possible value (for example, **"/camera/rgb/image_raw"**). You
   can find possible values click
   on the drop-down list on the
   **"Image"->"Image Topic"**. It works only for this session.

   If you want to make changes to all
   sessions, edit this parameter in the
   config: **robot.rviz**. You can find
   the path in
   **File->Open Config**. In **robot.rviz** find **"Class: rviz/Image"** and edit **"Image Topic"**.
2. Secondly, I'd like to add other decision. You can use current Topic (at least **"/camera/rgb/image_rect_color"**). Install "openni" and launch
   it:

   1. sudo apt-get install
      ros-indigo-openni-launch
   2. In a new
      terminal execute:  roslaunch
      openni_launch openni.launch
      load_driver:=false
      depth_registration:=true

---

Originally posted by [nampi](https://answers.ros.org/users/24910/nampi/) with karma: 77 on 2015-10-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-10-27**:
@nampi Thanks for digging in. Could you look at submitting it upstream to the [turtlebot_interactions repo](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_interactions). There might be some discussion about how to make it work for both simulation and the real robot but we should make it compatible for both.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is specific to Turtlebot3. The 'burger' model doesn't have a camera whereas the 'waffle_pi' does.
I had to reset the model to waffle_pi to get all the camera related topics.

---

Originally posted by [Shivendra](https://answers.ros.org/users/35418/shivendra/) with karma: 23 on 2020-04-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [trunc8](https://answers.ros.org/users/44889/trunc8/) on 2020-07-03**:
Thank you for this! I wish this information was included in beginner tutorials on Turtlebot3.